# unable to insert into sqlite_sequence table in sqlite3 swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

while trying to insert into sqlite_sequence it is showing syntax error

```
func CreateClientSequence(db:OpaquePointer?)
{

    let now = UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)


    if sqlite3_exec(db,"insert into sqlite_sequence (name,seq) values ('Customer',\(now)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error inserting table: \(errmsg)")
        print(now)
    }

    if sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error finalizing prepared statement: \(errmsg)")
    }

    statement = nil

}
```

and also tried with prepare both are not working

```
func CreateClientSequence(db:OpaquePointer?)
{

    let now = UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,"insert into sqlite_sequence (name,seq) values (?,?)", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
                }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, "Customer", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding foo: \(errmsg)")
    }
    if sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, now) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding foo: \(errmsg)")
    }


    if sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error finalizing prepared statement: \(errmsg)")
    }

    statement = nil

}
```

and the error is "error inserting table: near "1508821343": syntax error"

Comment: You are not even connecting the database by opening a statement.  There are more basic mistakes.

Comment: i will connect to database only once and i use the db variable throughout the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues:

1. You are missing closing parentheses in your first SQL:

   ```
   if sqlite3_exec(db,"insert into sqlite_sequence (name,seq) values ('Customer',\(now))", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK { ... }
   ```

   You had `)` to end your string interpolation of `now`, but not for the `values` SQL.
2. In your first attempt, you are performing `sqlite3_exec`, in which case `sqlite3_finalize` is not only not needed, but simply incorrect.
3. In your second example, you never call `sqlite3_step` to perform the prepared statement. Do that after you finish binding, but before you finalize.